# Convert decimal numpy array in 8 numpy arrays after binary transformation

Tags: python

I'm reading an image with OpenCV in gray scale, so i have a numpy array with values from 0 to 255.

I have to convert it to binary first.

From: `[dec, dec, dec, dec, dec, dec]`

To: `[bin, bin, bin, bin, bin, bin]`.

After that i have to build 8 numpy arrays with the bits of binary numpy array.

```
[bin[0], bin[0], bin[0], bin[0], bin[0], bin[0]]

[bin[1], bin[1], bin[1], bin[1], bin[1], bin[1]]

[bin[2], bin[2], bin[2], bin[2], bin[2], bin[2]]

[bin[3], bin[3], bin[3], bin[3], bin[3], bin[3]]

[bin[4], bin[4], bin[4], bin[4], bin[4], bin[4]]

[bin[5], bin[5], bin[5], bin[5], bin[5], bin[5]]
```

Regards!

Found a solution by this way.

```
import numpy as np

def toBin(dec):
    binary = []
    st = 0
    while(st < 8):
        binary.append(dec%2)
        dec = dec//2
        st = st + 1
    return binary

#Original image is an np.array object with (300x300) shape.
imgA = np.array([[42,0,52,234],[232,123,2,243],[24,231,245,21],[21,213,241,233]])

colsA = imgB.shape[0]
rowsA = imgB.shape[1]
cont = 0
new = []

binA = []
for row in imgA:
    for col in row:
        new.append(list(reversed(toBin(col))))
        cont = cont + 1
        if cont == colsA:
            cont = 0
            binA.append(new)
            new = []

npBinA = np.array(binA)
print(npBinA)
```

Output:
[Output in Python Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBrih.png)

Sorry if my question was not correctly formulated.
Thanks!.

Comment: What is your exact question? Where are you stuck? What have you tried so far (code, sample input, sample output)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
x = [10,2,4,5,7,8]

# convert decimal to binary
b = [bin(i)[2:] for i in x]

arr1 = []
for i in b:
    arr1.append([i]*6)

print(arr1)
```

**output**

```
[['1010', '1010', '1010', '1010', '1010', '1010'], 
 ['10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10'], 
 ['100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100'], 
 ['101', '101', '101', '101', '101', '101'], 
 ['111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '111'], 
 ['1000', '1000', '1000', '1000', '1000', '1000']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the problem. If you want to convert an int to binary you can use the numpy function:

```
bin1 = np.binary_repr()
```

This will return a string with the binary representation of your number. If you then want it as an int you can cast it:

```
first_number = int(bin1[0])
```

Hope that helps!!